# How to ignore only warnings with a specific message?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

As a workaround for [another issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/242423/38660) I would like to set up an error handler *only* for a specific warning. It should check whether the warning starts with a certain string, and if not it should *hand the warning over to the original handler.*

What I've got so far:

```
function filesize_for_url_ignoring_error_handler($severity, $message, $file, $line, $context) {
    if (strpos($message, 'Warning:  filesize(): stat failed for https://') === 0) {
        return;
    }
    restore_error_handler();
    throw new ErrorException($message, E_WARNING, $severity, $file, $line);
}

set_error_handler('filesize_for_url_ignoring_error_handler', E_WARNING);
$file = file_save($file);
restore_error_handler();
```

However, there seems to be several problems:

- I can't override the error handler only for a single error type. I've tried passing `E_ERROR`, `~E_WARNING`, `E_ALL` and `0` as the error type to `set_error_handler`, but it seems that setting the error handler with a given type *removes* the error handlers for all other types. Is that correct? I can work around this by setting the error handler for all error types.
- I don't know **how to handle the warning with the original error handler if it doesn't match the expected message.** Throwing an `ErrorException` is not the right thing - it results in a full stacktrace and the message does not end up in the Drupal watchdog log. Running `trigger_error` instead doesn't work either - I can see that the trigger is called (using `error_log`) but the message doesn't end up in the watchdog log.

Using Drupal 7.56 and PHP 5.4.

Comment: That seems like the wrong approach. Is it an option to simply suppress the warning from `filesize` by adding `@`? http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: No, the actual call is in third party code, and I really don't want to suppress all errors.

Comment: What happens if you call `filesize` or `stat` manually on the _uri_? These operations should succeed right?

Comment: See this https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36192/hide-errors-from-users-but-show-to-admin. The Disable Messages is the module you might be looking for.

Comment: @Halcyon It fails as described in the linked question.

Comment: @Anurag This is not about which messages are shown to users, it's about which messages are logged in the first place.

Comment: Why does it fail? Is the thing that you're trying to save not a `File`?

Comment: It is definitely a file. Please read the other question for details.

Answer (score 0):

90% solved by writing a custom error handler which **calls the original error handler if the message doesn't match:**

```
function filesize_for_url_ignoring_error_handler($severity, $message, $file, $line, $context) {
    global $originalErrorHandler;
    if (strpos($message, 'filesize(): stat failed for https://') !== 0) {
        $originalErrorHandler($severity, $message, $file, $line, $context);
    }
}

class […] {
    public function […] {
        $originalErrorHandler = set_error_handler('filesize_for_url_ignoring_error_handler');
        $file = file_save($file);
        restore_error_handler();
    }
}
```

Now only messages which do not start with "filesize(): stat failed for https://" are still logged in `file_save`. The only issue is that the watchdog log shows the message as originating in `filesize_for_url_ignoring_error_handler`, so I won't mark this as solved yet in case someone knows how to fix that (and ideally avoid using a global variable).